# CosmosDb shows inaccurate RU metrics

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The metrics(classic) under cosmosDB shows 0 RU for read region. Even if the read region is not used for read requests, some RUs must have been consumed for data writes. Please help to understand this. I have observed similar metrics in multi region writes as well.

Write region
[image]

Read region
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify "some RUs must have been consumed for data writes"? Writes will always go to the Write region, Read regions are only for Reads. Data replication (replicating writes from the Write region) does not consume RU.

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta I was referring to replication from write to read regions. I misunderstood that replication also consumes RU.  Does it works the same way in multi region writes and multi region reads enabled scenario ?

Comment: Replication does not consume RUs in single or multi write regions. 
You will see RU consumption on that graph for the operations you perform on the account, in your case, for the Reads you do to the secondary Read region and for the Reads/Writes you do to the Write region. In a multi write regions account, you will see the RU for the Reads/Writes you perform on each region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replication does not consume RUs in single or multi write regions.
You will see RU consumption on that graph for the operations you perform on the account, in your case, for the Reads you do to the secondary Read region and for the Reads/Writes you do to the Write region. In a multi write regions account, you will see the RU for the Reads/Writes you perform on each region.